# What is the right Way to export data to excel?

Tags: excel, laravel, export

Hi I am using  `maatwebsite/excel:^3.1` package to export and export data to excel but am getting `a 60 seconds exceeded`  error.

here is my `export.php` code

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Produit;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class ProductDataExport implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;

    private $products;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->products = Produit::all();
    }

    public function view() : View
    {
        return view('invoices-product',[
            'products_list' => Produit::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my `Produitcontroller` file :

```
public function exportProduct()
    {
        $product_list = Produit::all();
        return Excel::download(new ProductDataExport, 'products-data.xlsx');

    }
```

and this is the route code:

```
Route::post('products/export-excel',[ProduitController::class, 'exportProduct'])->name('products.download-excel');
```

and this is my form action:

```
<form action="{{ route('products.download-excel') }}" method="POST">
       @csrf
        <div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                 <div>Export Excel</div>
              </button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Honestly I haven't tried anything because I don't see what I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your instructions:

In your route definition, you should switch to using the GET method instead of POST:

```php
Route::get('products/export-excel',[ProduitController::class, 'exportProduct'])->name('products.download-excel');
```

Additionally, there's no need to use a form for this operation. You can simply use an anchor tag with the appropriate path:

```html
<a href="{{ route('products.download-excel') }}">Download Excel</a>
```

This will trigger the download when the link is clicked.